# Using JavaScript to add and delete rows from an HTML 5 form

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, html5, form

I am a JavaScript beginner. Here's a fictional example which isolates the functionality mentioned in the subject line. I hope to employ this functionality as part of a larger web application in the real world soon.

[Live example here](http://illumin-8.com/lunchtime/addingelements.html)

An HTML5 page containing a simple form with one row:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Add Elements to a Form</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="addrow">
    <label for="addnum">Add Rows:
    <input type="text" name="addnum" id="addnum" value="" size="2">
    </label>
    <input type="button" name="addbtn" id="addbtn" value="Go!">
</div>
<br>
<fieldset id="lunches"> 
    <legend>Let's do Lunch</legend>
    <div class="formrow">
        <span>My </span>
        <select name="lunch[]" class="dropdown">
            <option value="">Select a lunch item</option>
            <option value="baloney">Baloney</option>
            <option value="yogurt">Yogurt</option>
            <option value="apple">Apple</option>
            <option value="cheese">Government Cheese</option>
        </select>
        <span> has a </span>
        <select name="firstorlast[]" class="dropdown">
            <option value="first">First</option>
            <option value="second">Second</option>
        </select>
        <span> name. It's</span>
        <input type="text" name="name[]" value="Specify a Name" size="20">
    </div>
</fieldset>

<script src="js/utilities.js"></script>
<script src="js/addelements.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`addelements.js` which contains the functionality for adding and removing rows of input. Each added row will have a button which, when clicked, will delete the row from the form. The first row cannot and should not be deleted:

```
    window.onload = function() {
    'use strict';
    //U.addEvent is a cross-browser way to add an event handler to a DOM object.
    //U.$ is a shortcut to getElementById
    //Idea taken from Larry Ullman's "Modern Javascript: Develop and Design
    U.addEvent(U.$('addbtn'), 'click', addRows);
}

function addRows() {
    'use strict';
    var numRowsToAdd = U.$('addnum').value;
    for(var i = 0; i < numRowsToAdd; i++){
        addRow();
    }
}

function addRow() {
    'use strict';
    var sourceNode = document.querySelector('.formrow');
    var newRow = sourceNode.cloneNode(true);
    //every row except the first row should have a delete button associated with it.
    var delButton = document.createElement('input');
    delButton.className = 'delbtn';
    delButton.type = 'button';
    delButton.name = 'delbtn';
    delButton.value = 'Delete This Row';
    U.addEvent(delButton, 'click', function() {removeRow(delButton)});
    newRow.appendChild(delButton);
    var fieldset = U.$('lunches');
    fieldset.appendChild(newRow);
}

function removeRow(obj) {
    'use strict';
    var theRow = obj.parentNode;
    var theRowParent = theRow.parentNode;
    theRowParent.removeChild(theRow);
}
```

relevant code from `utilities.js`:

```
    var U = {

    // For getting the document element by ID:
    $: function(id) {
        'use strict';
        if (typeof id == 'string') {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }
    },

    addEvent: function(obj, type, fn) {
        'use strict';
        if (obj && obj.addEventListener) { // W3C
            obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
        } else if (obj && obj.attachEvent) { // Older IE
            obj.attachEvent('on' + type, fn);
        }
    }   
}
```

If you copy and save these into the proper files with the proper path structure, it should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/select-placeholder#answer-8442831 and make the first line non-selectable by HTML only.

It's done by making the first element **selected**, **disabled** and by adding a **display:none**.

Comment: As soon as I'm able to vote up your answer, I will.

Comment: @DeeDee I think you can accept it if you think it answered your question (tick box under the score).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using event delegation instead of adding event handlers to each 'Delete' button individually.

This can be done by attaching a click event listener to a parent element, then filtering the event target for a specified `className`.

For example, if we added a function `U.on()` as follows (and utilizing `U.addEvent()` that you already have):

```
!(function () {

'use strict';

/**
 * helper function to delegate/attach DOM events
 * @param  {String}   root  selector for event root element
 * @param  {String}   event single event name
 * @param  {String}   child className of target element
 * @param  {Function} fn    event handler
 */
function on(root, eventName, child, fn) {
    var to = document.querySelector(root);
    var handler = delegator(child, fn);
    U.addEvent(to, eventName, handler);
}

/**
 * fires event handler if event target matches className
 * @param  {String}   className class to match
 * @param  {Function} fn        event handler to call
 */
function delegator(className, fn) {
    return function (e) {
        if (e.target.classList.contains(className)) {
            fn.call(this, e);
        }
    };
}

U.on = on;

})();
```

We could delegate all of the 'Delete' button click events to the parent form element, by doing to following:

```
on('#lunches', 'click', 'delbtn', function (e) {
    removeRow(e.target);
});
```

This basically says, "If a click happens inside an element with the id `lunches`, and the click happened on an element with the class `.delbtn`, then call this function that I'm passing in as the last argument."